# How should I structure my OS X app's NSWindow / Views / ViewControllers?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

**The question is probably several smaller ones, but overall I'm really struggling to understand the "best practice" for structuring my Swift app's NSWindow / Views / ViewControllers. Can someone tell me what would be considered the "normal way" of doing this?**

I am building an app that has one window, containing a split-view. The left-hand split will contain a source-list and the right-hand will switch between one of several detail views. A very common scenario I'd have thought.

I'm aiming for OS X 10.10+ and I want to use ViewControllers for the significant views in my app. I'm not keen to use storyboards as I'm still learning my way and they seem a bit "magical" at this point.

What I've tried:

- I started by building all my views in IB directly inside `MainWindowController.xib`. I quickly got a bloated `MainWindowController.swift` as it contained all my code (e.g. it was the delegate and datasource for my source-list)

I decided to split everything up into NSViewControllers, but:

- I'm unsure where to instantiate them, particularly if their view is kept inside `MainWindowController.xib`
- is it weird to instantiate a view controller by dragging in a view controller in IB (i.e. so it appears in the "Objects" list on the LHS of IB)?
- does using NSViewControllers mandate that each controller's view is in its own XIB (assuming I don't want to create it in code)?
- if yes, it seems you'd have many fairly pointless XIB's e.g. having a whole XIB containing nothing more than an empty NSWindow
- if that's true, would you typically ditch the XIB for the pointless ones, and create its view in code (e.g. create the NSWindow in code)?

When I went ahead and split it all up into multiple XIB's and corresponding view controllers (creating my NSWindow in code for the above reasons), I got some way but noticed my split view no longer had a divider. My research indicated that this will happen if you sub-class NSSplitView but I don't think I'm doing that (at least not deliberately).

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let splitViewController = CMSplitViewController()
        let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: splitViewController)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        self.window = window
    }
```

and

```
class CMSplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {

    override var nibName: String? {
        return "CMSplitViewController"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }
}
```

...where `CMSplitViewController.xib` contains just a single NSSplitView (and child views of course), dragged into IB from the object library.

Comment: I would recommend familiarizing yourself with Storyboards — the new and improved NSViewController and subclasses are designed to work with them. In particular, the NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier methods are an easy and straightforward way to create windows and views, each with their specific controllers. Get your feet wet and try out Storyboards, they'll make things much easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your great advice @ElmerCat — I have done as suggested and am loving it. As a new Cocoa developer my code suddenly feels well structured, simpler, and much more fine-grained, with better separation-of-concerns. If you'd like to make your comment an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the solution.